# Visual basic send char null to com port

Tags: vb6

I have a project write a program to send bunch of data into credit card terminal in Visual Basic 6.

[Terminal specs](http://www.spad.gov.my/sites/default/files/cashless_payment_terminal_specification_for_obu_v1.pdf)

The problem I facing now is on field LLLL which is the length of the message data. Let's say the length is 35, how I gonna write it in char?

I tried to use Chr$(&H0) & Chr$(&H35), but its always return empty to me.

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: What means "return empty to me"? You can't visualise this string. You can try to use fixed length string (String*2) or Byte array - depend on Terminal/RS232 API.

Comment: Almost all serious use of the MSComm32.ocx should be done in Binary mode using Byte arrays.  Most likely after the String gets converted from Unicode to ANSI the NUL character is being taken as a terminating delimiter rather than a character... which it isn't anyway.  A fixed-length String doesn't buy you anything here either.